# Recursive function to select option

Tags: php, mysql, function

I have a Recursive function that works with 3 depts. My problem is that I want to display them in 3 different select option boxes based on dept.

Like this:

http://ixxes.com/websites/adres/Naamloos.png
can someone help me please!

```
function categories($parent_id = '0'){

$return = '';

$sQuery = mysql_query("SELECT id, name, parent_id FROM tbl_categories WHERE parent_id = '" . $parent_id . "' ORDER BY name ASC") or die(mysql_error());

while($details = mysql_fetch_assoc($sQuery)){

    $return .= '<li>';
    $return .= '<a href="category?id=' . $details['id'] . '">' . $details['name'] . '</a>';

    $uQuery = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM tbl_categories WHERE parent_id = '" . $details['id'] ."'") or die(mysql_error());

    $return .= (mysql_num_rows($uQuery) ? '<ul>' . categories($details['id']) . '</ul>' : '');
    $return .= '</li>';
}
return $return;
```

}

Comment: The table attribute pattern is not clear in the qstn

Comment: Strongly suggest you separate out the sql from the html ! Also (and not entirely unrelated), why not just return the entire dataset (unless it's vast) and handle the display logic entirely within javascript.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, maby it's better to do this with an ajax call?